# Which RAID level gives me protection against bit errors?

Tags: raid, storage

I might confuse things with parity here, but does any of the RAID levels except RAID2 employ any means against silent bit corruption in the data? What about checksumming? I am not talking about hardware failures of any sort.

Comment: RAID 3, RAID 4, RAID 5, RAID 6 all provide some sort of byte/block/bit striping and some sort of parity.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_2):

> RAID 2 is the only standard RAID level, other than some
>   implementations of RAID 6, which can automatically recover accurate
>   data from single-bit corruption in data. Other RAID levels can detect
>   single-bit corruption in data, or can sometimes reconstruct missing
>   data, but cannot reliably resolve contradictions between parity bits
>   and data bits without human intervention.